# Unable to Include Own NuGet Package in Project (Winform)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, nuget

I'm kind of new to NuGet.
So, I have this Winform project where I need to use my own published NuGet Package (a class library which also use winform). I installed my package to the project, but I was unable to include the package in my project. It keeps getting the error:
[image: include error]

This is the published package and its code.
[image]

```
//Nuget Package, from file WhatsappContactLib-NETFramework.csproj, different solution than the main project
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WhatsappContactLibNETF
{
    public class WhatsappContactLib
    {
        private void sendWhatsapp(string number, string message)
        {
            try
            {
                if(number == "")
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("No number assigned to this person. Please contact your admin.");
                }
                if(number.Length <= 0)
                {
                    number = "+62" + number;
                }
                number = number.Replace(" ", "");
                number = number.Replace("-", "");
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=" + number + "&text-" + message);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
        

    }
}
```

This is the code where I will use the mentioned NuGet Package:

```
//Winform code in the main project
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using WhatsappContactLibNETF; //red squiggly lines here, with the error above mentioned

namespace DTETI_Room_Booker.Forms
{
    public partial class FormContact : Form
    {
        private string number1 = "+6281234567890"
        public FormContact()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            LoadTheme();
        }
        public void LoadTheme()
        {
            foreach (Control btns in this.Controls)
            {
                if (btns.GetType() == typeof(Button))
                {
                    Button btn = (Button)btns;
                    btn.BackColor = ThemeColor.PrimaryColor;
                    btn.ForeColor = Color.White;
                    btn.FlatAppearance.BorderColor = ThemeColor.SecondaryColor;
                }
            }
        }

        private void lblContact1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            WhatsappContactLib.sendWhatsapp(number1, txtBoxMessage1.Text); //does not exist in current context
        }

        private void btnSend1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btnSend2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btnSend3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

    }
}
```

I don't get where I went wrong, because in Microsoft tutorial I should only need to use using  and then use the package. Any answer would be helpful, thanks in advance.

Edit 1:
Here is the csproj file.

```
//csproj file
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProjectGuid>{90427756-2539-4A22-94D0-187955C98A4B}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <RootNamespace>DTETI_Room_Booker</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>DTETI Room Booker</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.8</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
    <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
    <Deterministic>true</Deterministic>
    <TargetFrameworkProfile />
    <IsWebBootstrapper>false</IsWebBootstrapper>
    <PublishUrl>publish\</PublishUrl>
    <Install>true</Install>
    <InstallFrom>Disk</InstallFrom>
    <UpdateEnabled>false</UpdateEnabled>
    <UpdateMode>Foreground</UpdateMode>
    <UpdateInterval>7</UpdateInterval>
    <UpdateIntervalUnits>Days</UpdateIntervalUnits>
    <UpdatePeriodically>false</UpdatePeriodically>
    <UpdateRequired>false</UpdateRequired>
    <MapFileExtensions>true</MapFileExtensions>
    <ApplicationRevision>0</ApplicationRevision>
    <ApplicationVersion>1.0.0.%2a</ApplicationVersion>
    <UseApplicationTrust>false</UseApplicationTrust>
    <BootstrapperEnabled>true</BootstrapperEnabled>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="WhatsappContactLibNETF" Version="1.1.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces.1.1.1\lib\net461\Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Bcl.HashCode, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Bcl.HashCode.1.1.1\lib\net461\Microsoft.Bcl.HashCode.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Data.Sqlite, Version=3.1.32.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.Core.3.1.32\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.DotNet.PlatformAbstractions, Version=3.1.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.DotNet.PlatformAbstractions.3.1.6\lib\net45\Microsoft.DotNet.PlatformAbstractions.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=3.1.32.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.3.1.32\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Abstractions, Version=3.1.32.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Abstractions.3.1.32\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Abstractions.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational, Version=3.1.32.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational.3.1.32\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite, Version=3.1.32.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.Core.3.1.32\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions, Version=3.1.32.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions.3.1.32\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory, Version=3.1.32.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory.3.1.32\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration, Version=3.1.32.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.3.1.32\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions, Version=3.1.32.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions.3.1.32\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder, Version=3.1.32.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder.3.1.32\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, Version=3.1.32.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.3.1.32\lib\net461\Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions, Version=3.1.32.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.3.1.32\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel, Version=3.1.25.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel.3.1.25\lib\net451\Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging, Version=3.1.32.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.3.1.32\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions, Version=3.1.32.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions.3.1.32\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Options, Version=3.1.32.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.Options.3.1.32\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Options.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives, Version=3.1.32.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.3.1.32\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Newtonsoft.Json, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.9.0.1\lib\net45\Newtonsoft.Json.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="SQLitePCLRaw.batteries_v2, Version=2.1.2.1721, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8226ea5df37bcae9, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_e_sqlite3.2.1.2\lib\net461\SQLitePCLRaw.batteries_v2.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="SQLitePCLRaw.core, Version=2.1.2.1721, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1488e028ca7ab535, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\SQLitePCLRaw.core.2.1.2\lib\netstandard2.0\SQLitePCLRaw.core.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="SQLitePCLRaw.provider.dynamic_cdecl, Version=2.1.2.1721, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b68184102cba0b3b, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\SQLitePCLRaw.provider.dynamic_cdecl.2.1.2\lib\netstandard2.0\SQLitePCLRaw.provider.dynamic_cdecl.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System">
      <HintPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.8\System.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Buffers, Version=4.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.Buffers.4.5.1\lib\net461\System.Buffers.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Collections.Immutable, Version=1.2.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.Collections.Immutable.1.7.1\lib\net461\System.Collections.Immutable.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.ComponentModel.Annotations, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.ComponentModel.Annotations.4.7.0\lib\net461\System.ComponentModel.Annotations.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource, Version=4.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.4.7.1\lib\net46\System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Memory, Version=4.0.1.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.Memory.4.5.4\lib\net461\System.Memory.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Numerics" />
    <Reference Include="System.Numerics.Vectors, Version=4.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.Numerics.Vectors.4.5.0\lib\net46\System.Numerics.Vectors.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe, Version=4.0.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.4.7.1\lib\net461\System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.4.0.0\lib\net45\System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions, Version=4.2.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.4.5.4\lib\net461\System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
    <Reference Include="System.Deployment" />
    <Reference Include="System.Drawing" />
    <Reference Include="System.Net.Http" />
    <Reference Include="System.Windows.Forms" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="FormMainMenu.cs">
      <SubType>Form</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="FormMainMenu.Designer.cs">
      <DependentUpon>FormMainMenu.cs</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Forms\FormAccount.cs">
      <SubType>Form</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Forms\FormAccount.Designer.cs">
      <DependentUpon>FormAccount.cs</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Forms\FormContact.cs">
      <SubType>Form</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Forms\FormContact.Designer.cs">
      <DependentUpon>FormContact.cs</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Forms\FormFAQ.cs">
      <SubType>Form</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Forms\FormFAQ.Designer.cs">
      <DependentUpon>FormFAQ.cs</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Forms\FormHome.cs">
      <SubType>Form</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Forms\FormHome.Designer.cs">
      <DependentUpon>FormHome.cs</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Forms\FormRooms.cs">
      <SubType>Form</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Forms\FormRooms.Designer.cs">
      <DependentUpon>FormRooms.cs</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Program.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
    <Compile Include="ThemeColor.cs" />
    <EmbeddedResource Include="FormMainMenu.resx">
      <DependentUpon>FormMainMenu.cs</DependentUpon>
    </EmbeddedResource>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Forms\FormAccount.resx">
      <DependentUpon>FormAccount.cs</DependentUpon>
    </EmbeddedResource>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Forms\FormContact.resx">
      <DependentUpon>FormContact.cs</DependentUpon>
    </EmbeddedResource>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Forms\FormFAQ.resx">
      <DependentUpon>FormFAQ.cs</DependentUpon>
    </EmbeddedResource>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Forms\FormHome.resx">
      <DependentUpon>FormHome.cs</DependentUpon>
    </EmbeddedResource>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Forms\FormRooms.resx">
      <DependentUpon>FormRooms.cs</DependentUpon>
    </EmbeddedResource>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Properties\Resources.resx">
      <Generator>ResXFileCodeGenerator</Generator>
      <LastGenOutput>Resources.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </EmbeddedResource>
    <Compile Include="Properties\Resources.Designer.cs">
      <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
      <DependentUpon>Resources.resx</DependentUpon>
      <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
    </Compile>
    <None Include="packages.config" />
    <None Include="Properties\Settings.settings">
      <Generator>SettingsSingleFileGenerator</Generator>
      <LastGenOutput>Settings.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
    </None>
    <Compile Include="Properties\Settings.Designer.cs">
      <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
      <DependentUpon>Settings.settings</DependentUpon>
      <DesignTimeSharedInput>True</DesignTimeSharedInput>
    </Compile>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="App.config" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="assets\images\dteti-transparent.png" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="assets\icons\Arrow-1.png" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="assets\icons\Help-1.png" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="assets\icons\Home-1.png" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="assets\icons\List-1.png" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="assets\icons\Phone-1.png" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="assets\icons\Write-1.png" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="Resources\Home-1.bmp" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="assets\icons\Arrow-1.bmp" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="assets\icons\Help-1.bmp" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="assets\icons\Home-1.bmp" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="assets\icons\List-1.bmp" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="assets\icons\Phone-1.bmp" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="assets\icons\Write-1.bmp" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="assets\images\RoomPicture\meeting-room.jpeg" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="assets\images\RoomPicture\discussionRoom.jpg" />
    <Content Include="AccountsDatabase.mdf">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
    <Content Include="AccountsDatabase_log.ldf">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <DependentUpon>AccountsDatabase.mdf</DependentUpon>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <BootstrapperPackage Include=".NETFramework,Version=v4.8">
      <Visible>False</Visible>
      <ProductName>Microsoft .NET Framework 4.8 %28x86 and x64%29</ProductName>
      <Install>true</Install>
    </BootstrapperPackage>
    <BootstrapperPackage Include="Microsoft.Net.Framework.3.5.SP1">
      <Visible>False</Visible>
      <ProductName>.NET Framework 3.5 SP1</ProductName>
      <Install>false</Install>
    </BootstrapperPackage>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <WCFMetadata Include="Connected Services\" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
</Project>
```

Comment: Add your csproj file to this showing where the nuget package is installed (to confirm it's correctly installed)

Comment: @gilliduck I've added the csproj. Thanks for checking in to this.

Comment: Is your NuGet package code targeting the same .NET Framework as the project using the NuGet package?

Comment: This is .Net Framework? Is the nuget package also Framework? As @KarenPayne mentioned, you need to make sure all your versions match or are compatible.

Comment: Yes, I believe my nuget package is also a .NET Framework since I used the class library (.NET Framework) template. The property also shows that it is a .NET Framework (4.8, to be exact. The same as the main project).

Comment: In your csproj, I see `<HintPath>..\packages`, which tells me that `packages.config` is used. However, I also see a `<PackageReference`. NuGet doesn't allow a project to use both PackageReference and packages.config for a single project, it must be one, or the other. Therefore, your project configuration is not valid, probably contributing to the error. I suggest delete the PackageReference line, then use the UI in Visual Studio to install the package, don't edit the csproj directly.